# Installing Mongodb to existing Node app causes application to stop working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

I have built a node application that uses socket.io and express.
A lot of development has passed with this app but I finally decided to add MongoDB to this app. When I install mongo with npm, everything with socket.io stops working completely. No errors are shown on the client or server side. My cpu usage on chrome spikes up to a crazy amount.

It is a really odd issue because mongo does connect to my server successfully and the app works perfectly without mongo installed into the dependencies.

My server side node application has this structure:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

var url = 'mongodb://hidingmyipaddress:27017';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

   socket.on('name', function(rm, qqquota){
```

Comment: cpu usage in chrome spiking indicates the websocket is being terminated and reopened/recreated. You're probably doing something down lower inside `socket.on` that's failing and crashing and closing the websocket causing the client to re-connect.

Comment: Maybe you should move the socket code out of the MongoClient connect function?